# Regex exact space match

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to find proper regex which match exact number of spaces. Input text can contain any other literals.

If I want 2 spaces for instance the pattern should match:

```
" AX "
"  AX"
"AX BX CX"
```

and any other combinations with two spaces. My current regex is:

```
"^(([^[:space:]]*\\s[^[:space:]]*){2})$"
```

However the regex always find two occurrence of pattern. In case of "AX BX CX" input it will find "AX BX CX" and " CX".

For testing purpose I use simple perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

if ($#ARGV + 1 != 2) {
    print "Usage: match.pl pattern input\n";
    exit;
}

$pattern = $ARGV[0];
$input = $ARGV[1];

if ($input =~ /$pattern/) {
    print "Matched: $1  - $2 \n";
} else {
    print "Not matched.\n";
}
```

Comment: In Perl, the extension is better written from `[^[:space:]]` to `[[:^space:]]`

Comment: Better not to use Posix in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you're looking for is `[^ ]* [^ ]\+ [^ ]*`. Only when you're looking for *more* than two spaces you should use `{}`. For instance, three spaces would be matched: `[^ ]*\( [^ ]\+\)\{2\} [^ ]*`.

Test it out using:

```
grep '[^ ]*\( [^ ]\+\)\{2\} [^ ]*'
```

or

```
grep '[^ ]* [^ ]\+ [^ ]*'
```

If two consecutive spaces are allowed, you could use:

```
grep '\([^ ]* \)\{2\}'
```

Increase the `2` for more spaces.

In your case I'd try:

```
([^[:space:]]*[:space:]){2}
```

to match two spaces, if you want two spaces exactly on the line.

```
^([^[:space:]]*[:space:]){2}[^[:space:]]*$
```

Where we padded the double space with potential non space characters.

Now to catch the entire line, place it in a group:

```
(^([^[:space:]]*[:space:]){2}[^[:space:]]*$)
```

All that's left is to ignore the middle group, which we do by adding `?:` at the beginning of the group. Making **the final regex**:

```
(^(?:[^[:space:]]*[:space:]){2}[^[:space:]]*$)
```

Comment: You can factor one of these out since they are redundant. ^`[^[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]*` ...

Comment: Yes obviously, how did I miss that. I guess my method was a bit too constructive . Thanks for pointing that out!!

Comment: Unfortunately the result is same. If I use your final regex with input "AX BX CX" the result will be "BX ". I probably need to put whole regex into bracket but than I will receive again two results. One is expected  "AX BX CX" but the second is only "BX ".

Comment: Oh then use `(^(?:[^[:space:]]*[:space:]){2}[^[:space:]]*$)` as sln suggested. If `?:` are the first two chars of a group, it doesn't get captures.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with a match-style regex is tricky. I might recommend something more along the lines of the following code:

```
my (@fields) = split( /\s/, $input );
if( scalar( @fields ) < 3 ) {
    warn "'$input' didn't have enough spaces!";
elsif( scalar( @fields ) > 3 ) {
    warn "'$input' had too many spaces!";
}
```

`split`, if used this way, will take a string like `'  C'` and divide it into `( '', '', 'C' )`.

Answer (score 0):

This works. Only two spaces in string.
It uses the infamous un-rolled loop method.

```
 # ^[^ ]*(?:[ ][^ ]*){2}$

 ^ 
 [^ ]* 
 (?:
      [ ] 
      [^ ]* 
 ){2}
 $
```